# It's regarding centripetal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

[image: Picture of an object in a vertical circle]

Above is the image of an object made to revolve in a vertical circle. The tension of the string at any point is also given in the above image. But my question is, shouldn't the equation be as below? Also, what is $W\sin \theta$ here? Is it reducing the velocity of the object since it's acting in the opposite direction of the velocity?

[image: Equation I'm expecting to be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really nice to work in a polar co-ordinate when you are dealing with circular motion. Recall that for polar co-ordinate we have
$$\mathbf{F}=m(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2)\hat{r}+m(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})\hat{\theta}$$

In our case we have
$$m(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2)=-T+W\cos\theta$$

$$m(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})=W\sin\theta$$

Since $r=R=$ constant, $a_r=-R(\dot{\theta}^2)=-v^2/R,$

$$-mr\dot{\theta}^2=-T+W\cos\theta$$
$$T=\frac{mv^2}{R}+W\cos\theta$$
and $$mR\ddot{\theta}=W\sin\theta$$

That explains the above equation.

---

Note : A string can pull but not push, so that $T$ can't be negative. This requires that $mv^2/R W\cos\theta \geq 0$. The maximum value of $W\cos\theta$ occure when the mass is vertically up; in this case $mv^2/R>W$. If this conditon is not satisfied, the mass does not follow a circular path but starts to fall; $\ddot{r} \not= 0$.

Comment: Well then why doesn't it work with the net of all forces being zero for that object to remain in it's path?

Comment: if the net force will be zero then how does the bob do motion.

Comment: You may cofused with the force in non-inertial frame and inertial frame. If you want to do the problem in in non-inertial frame(rotating frame) you  can use centrifugal force which is directly outward so you tension inward and other two outward and that will give the same equation.

Comment: Well due to the velocity of the tangential direction. If the object is moving in the tangential direction with constant speed, shouldn't the vector sum of the components of forces in normal direction be zero?

Comment: Yeah in the radial part there is no net force and we can say that radial part of the force due to $\ddot{r}$ should be zero. and thus what I did by putting it to zero though due to change in direction of motion there is force so called centripetal force.

Comment: To maintain equillibrium this will be equal to net force and that is $-T +W\cos \theta$.

Comment: Which "above equation" is explained?  Something is disturbing about the last equation.  In uniform circular motion $\ddot{\theta}=0\,$ so  $\,0 = W\sin\theta$  and  $\theta = 0$ always??

Comment: @garyp It's not a uniform circular motion as gravity is involved here.

Comment: One more thing to note that $mv^2/r>W$, if this condition is not satisfied, the mass does not follow a circular path but starts to fall, and $\ddot{r}$ is no longer zero.

Comment: If there are no net forces, doesn't that mean sum of all forces equals zero? as I did in the second picture of above?

Comment: You have written the wrong equation it should be $F_{net}=0=mg\cos \theta-mv^2/r-T=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to keep in my mind here is that centripetal force is not a real force (**real** in the sense that it doesn't have its origin like other forces and) and it doesn't affect things like other forces .

**It is just a net component of all the forces acting on a body towards the center of the circle**.

So , the forces acting on the body in your case is *tension* and *mg* only and not centripetal force . So if you find the net component of both the forces **along the center** you get

$T - mg\cos \theta$ and **this is your centripetal force**.

So $T - mg\cos \theta = \frac{mv^2}{r}$

The picture of the circle you have drawn gives a wrong information about centripetal force and this caused your confusion. But The equation in your book is mathematically correct.

> Also, what is $W\sin \theta$ here
> It is just a component of the weight along the tangential direction and yes it slows down the object.

**Note** : Centrifugal forces are not real in the sense that they are frame dependent but centripetal forces are not frame dependent and I have mentioned why I wrote it to be non - real force.

Hope it helps .

Comment: centripetal forces aren't real? i thought it was centrifugal force which was not real.

Comment: if it slows down the velocity how come we have the object moving at constant speed?

Comment: The centripetal force is a real force. It’s the centrifugal corce that is pseudo force

Comment: @Sandil Adhikari by real I didn't mean to say frame dependent like centrifugal . I meant to say that it doesn't have its own identity and is just a net component of other forces.

Comment: @Bob D I have edited my answer. Is it okay now ?

Comment: @Sandil Adhikari if it is a vertical circular motion it must slow down since gravity has some components in tangential direction and it can't have uniform motion.  It is similar to the case when you throw a ball upward. Does it move with a constant velocity ? No. However in your case there is one more force : tension but it doesn't affect the tangential velocity since it is perpendicular to it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "having its own identity." The centripetal force is the tension force in the string.  You are therefore essentially saying that tension is not a real force in the sense that it doesn't have its own identity? Tension is an example of one of the four fundamental forces, in this case electromagnetic.

Comment: @Bob D okay I have edited it. Is it okay to say that it doesn't have its own origin ? It is just a force towards the center  .

Comment: @BobD Tension is not the centripetal force.   There is a speed $\sqrt{gr}$ for which the tension at the top of motion is zero.  But at that point the object is still moving in a circle at constant speed, so there must be a centripetal force.  In this case, the centripetal force is $mg$

Comment: If centripetal forces are real, why is it equal to the net of other forces but rather not act like any other forces?

Comment: @Sandil Adhikari because there is no reason for it to exist. I think you are being confused with the word **real**. Whenever you see a circular motion , you can notice that there is something which is causing it. This something applies a force and we call it centripetal force

Comment: Yes, I'm very confused right now. So basically, if there are no other forces, the centripetal forces cannot exist like gravitational force or frictional force, it just cannot exist on it's own? It is a result some other forces acting in a certain way? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @Sandil Adhikari yes .

Comment: In what other case something like this happen? Can you give me another example in which the net of all forces is another force (not necessarily circular motion)? Also whis frame dependent force or frame independent force?

Comment: @Sandil Adhikari centripetal force is not another force . It is just a name given to the net force along center. Just like your parents named you , scientists called this centripetal .

Comment: @Ankit OHHH, I get it now. Thanks man. You've been really helpful.